# Intellij regex find and replace up to open parenthesis

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I want to use replacement groups in IntelliJ to find and replace all occurrences of:

```
SomeText(
```

with

```
SomeText = new TestThing("SomeText",
```

Where SomeText is the replacement group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use capturing group.

Replace:

```
([A-Za-z]+)\(
```

- OR `^([A-Za-z]+)\(`   if you want the text only match at the beginning of the lines

with:

```
$1 = new TestThing("$1",
```

---

According to the [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/find-and-replace-in-path.html), JetBrains use `$n` form for backreference.